# NeoVim : Can we "insert literally" every ASCII symbol with `<c-v>` ? (including delete `^?` )

Tags: neovim, insert-mode, control-character, ascii

In insert or command mode, the printable ASCII chars, like `a` can be insert with just `a`
(we don't need `<c-v>` for those ones, but most of them will still work with `<c-v>letter` ).

If I type, let's say, `<c-v><c-a>`, in insert mode, it will put a `^A` with the `SpecialKey` color, meaning it's actually the char with hex value `01` (we can check this with `ga`), and it's the case for most `<c-v><c-letter>` shortcuts :
It usually puts the ASCII char with value `letter modulo 32`, so, it's supposed to let me write almost every ASCII chars.

I still see 4 main exceptions to this rule :

1. `<c-v><c-@>` (or `<c-v><c-space>`) will put the chars `<c-space>` (several letters), and not `^@` as I expected.
   There is actually a simple way to write `^@` : `<c-v><c-j>`.
2. So, I have no way to write `^J`, but I guess `^J` is used to the "visual" newlines in NeoVim :
   I checked with `xxd` on an empty file, doing : `i00000000: 0a0a<Esc>:.!xxd -r<c-m>` gives me 2 lines, meaning the `0a`th ASCII char is used for that. So, I think there is no way to see a `^J` (or only instead of newline with some option), am I right ? In a certain sense, we can say that `<c-m>` or `<Enter>` alone is a way to insert the char with hex value `0a`.
3. Either `<c-i>` (tabulation) or `<c-v><c-i>` display a tabulation char, but the tabulation isn't displayed as `<c-i>`. It's only displayed as some chars with variable length, depending on options like `listchars` or `tabstop`. I don't know if there is a way to display it as `^I` instead of "a large space", (but this is not my main question).
4. For delete : `<c-v><del>` will print `<del>` and not `^?` as I expected. This one is the more problematic, because I haven't found something simple to insert the char with hex value `7f` (ie the last ASCII char).

I tried the same with `vim`, and the behavior differ for `1.` and `4.` :
with `vim`, I can type every ASCII char easily, while I can't with `neovim`.

I know the ASCII `delete` char can be typed in a harder way, with `<c-v>x7f`. It's a bit long to do.

Is there a reason why **exactly one** ASCII char (the delete) can't be inserted in text in a simple way ?

**main question:** Is there somewhere an option I can configure to tell `neovim` to get the literal `^?` instead of its name `<del>` ?
(I mean something other than explicitly remapping the shortcuts sequence and explicitly describing the hex value I want, else, the command `inoremap <c-v><del> <c-v>x7f` can in some sense solve my problem).

I saw some people has [almost what I search](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20576/pressing-shift-backspace-in-insert-mode-types-instead-of-backspacing/20586#20586), but didn't wanted it (for this case, it was without pressing `<c-v>`). I am pretty sure they didn't explicitly remapped something to `<c-v>x7f`, or at least, this kind of post let me think there could be an option.
In other words, can we chose somewhere how key names (like `<F1>`, or `<c-left>` or anything) are displayed after `<c-v>` ?

---

**Note :** I tested in several contexts (both `vim` and `neovim`, and each of them with 4 terminals : `st`, `gnome-terminal`, `konsole` and `guake`, so, at least it's not an "issue" related to one specific terminal) and got exactly the same result every time I do this with `neovim`. Versions are :

- `neovim` : 0.4.3
- `vim` : 8.1.2269

**Note :** I also tried with `zsh` shell alone, because there is a similar feature : `<c-v><BS>` writes `^?` in `zsh` (and it also writes `^?` in `vim` if I edit the shell command with `vim`, using `<c-x><c-e>` shortcut from `zsh`). Also, `<c-v><c-@>` writes `^@` in `zsh`, so, if there is a way to tell `vim` to behave like `zsh` for this part, it will be a little better for me.

**Note :** To get `^?` with `zsh`, I needed to use the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key, not the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, while `^?` is indeed called `DEL` when I search it in `man 7 ascii`. `<c-v><del>` on `zsh` writes `^[[3~` (an `Escape` or `^[`, followed by 3 printable chars). Same for other shells (at least `bash`). Same for `vim`. So, I also tried `<c-v><BS>` in `neovim`, but it only writes `<BS>` as text, neither `^h` nor `^?`.

**Edit :** I discovered that my `vim` command is `/usr/bin/vim`, but it's actually a symlink to a symlink to `/usr/bin/nvim`, so, it ran `neovim` instead. I need to explicitly type `/usr/bin/vim.basic` to launch the true `vim`. In `vim` only, the `<c-v><BS>` writes `^?` as I wanted. So, I guess my problem is related `neovim` only. I edited this in my text. Now, when I write `vim`, I'm actually referring to the command `/usr/bin/vim.basic` that launches it (and not the `vim` command that launched `neovim`). I also added the `neovim` tag.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122994/discussion-on-question-by-ewen-goisot-can-we-insert-literally-every-ascii-symb).